# Find the matrix representing T with respect to alpha. Find the characteristic of [T]alpha

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\textsf{T}:\,\textsf{P}_2(\mathbb R)\to \textsf{P}_2(\mathbb R)$  be the linear transformation defined by
$$\textsf{T}(p(x)) = p(1)(x^2 + x) + p(0)$$
$\textrm{(a)}$ Let $α = \{x^2,x,1\}$ be the standard ordered basis for $\textsf{P}_2(\mathbb R)$. Find the matrix
representing $\textsf{T}$ with respect to $\alpha$, i.e. find $[\textsf{T}]_\alpha$.

$\textrm{(b)}$ Find the characteristic polynomial of $[\textsf{T}]_\alpha$.

$\textrm{(c)}$ Find the eigenvalues of $[\textsf{T}]_\alpha$.

$\textrm{(d)}$ Show that $\textsf{T}$ is diagonalizable, that is, find an ordered basis $\beta$ for $\textsf{P}_2(\mathbb R)$ such that $[\textsf{T}]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix.

I'm really confused about how to find the value of $p(1)$ and $p(0)$ here. Can you please explain how to find them?

Comment: For example, if $p(x)=x^2+x$ then $p(1)=1^2+1=2$ and $p(0)=0^2+0=0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\textsf{T}:\, P_2(\mathbb{R})\to P_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by
$$\textsf{T}(p(x))=p(1)(x^2+x)+p(0)$$
and $\alpha=\{x^2,x,1\}$ a basis for $P_2(\mathbb{R})$. For $(1)$, we need to calculate 
$\textsf{T}(x^2)$, $\textsf{T}(x)$ and $\textsf{T}(1)$ and then put them as a linear combination of the elements in $\alpha$:
$$\textsf{T}(x^2)=1^2(x^2+x)+0^2=1\cdot x^2+1\cdot x+0\cdot 1$$ 
$$\textsf{T}(x)=1(x^2+x)+0=1\cdot x^2+1\cdot x+0\cdot 1$$
$$\textsf{T}(1)=1(x^2+x)+1=1\cdot x^2+1\cdot x+1\cdot 1$$
Then, we put the respective coefficients as columns of the matrix
$$[\textsf{T}]_\alpha=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1\\1&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: For the second, compute $\det([\textsf{T}]_\alpha-\lambda I)$.